# using RestKit to serialize an object with a subobject [POSTing]

Tags: ios, restkit

I have the following objects setup:

```
RKObjectMapping* geoPointMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CRGeoPoint class]];

geoPointMapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = YES;
[geoPointMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
    @"longitude", @"longitude",
    @"latitude", @"latitude",
    nil];
[objectManager.mappingProvider registerMapping:geoPointMapping withRootKeyPath:@"geometry"];

RKObjectMapping* criteriaMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CRCriteria class]];

criteriaMapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = YES;
[criteriaMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
    @"type", @"type",
    @"geometry", @"geometry",
    @"fromDate", @"fromDate",
    @"toDate", @"toDate",
    @"radius", @"radius",
    nil];
[objectManager.mappingProvider registerMapping:criteriaMapping withRootKeyPath:@"criteria"];
```

But when I try and send the query (with a geometry object). I keep
getting this error:

> error received Error Domain=JKErrorDomain Code=-1 "Unable to serialize
>   object class CRGeoPoint."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inbound and outbound mapping information is handled separately by `RKObjectMappingProvider`. You've configured the inbound mapping in that code (downloading the data from your server). But--[as pointed out by Shane Zatezalo](http://groups.google.com/group/restkit/browse_thread/thread/f38b055c1f824c44) on the RestKit group--you also need to add a serialization mapping for RestKit to know how to turn your objects into JSON (or whatever other serialization format you might be using).

Check out the [Object Mapping tutorial's](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md) section on Object Serialization. And take a look at the [source for the mapping provider](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Code/ObjectMapping/RKObjectMappingProvider.m) to reassure yourself that these things are separate.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the doc, both you and Shane were partially correct. But the doc pointed the way to the full answer. I needed to not only did you have to create the inverse mapping but you also had to specify which mapping to use for a relationship.

Comment: Yeah I got confused by this for quite a while. Eventually I realized that I needed to register the mappings (keyed by resource path) with the mapping provider and separately register the classes resource paths with router'.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

The solution was two-fold. First I had to specify the inverse mapping as Sixten pointed out below, second I had to specify the mapping to use for the CRGeoPoint class on the CRCriteria object. Code below:

```
RKObjectMapping* geoPointMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CRGeoPoint class]];

geoPointMapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = YES;

[objectManager.mappingProvider registerMapping:geoPointMapping withRootKeyPath:@"geometry"];

// Build a serialization mapping by inverting our object mapping. Includes attributes and relationships
RKObjectMapping* geoPointSerializationMapping = [geoPointMapping inverseMapping];
// You can customize the mapping here as necessary -- adding/removing mappings
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:geoPointSerializationMapping forClass:[CRGeoPoint class]]; 

RKObjectMapping* criteriaMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CRCriteria class]];

criteriaMapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = YES;
[criteriaMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
 @"type", @"type",
 @"fromDate", @"fromDate",
 @"toDate", @"toDate",
 @"radius", @"radius",
 nil];
[criteriaMapping mapKeyPath:@"geometry" toRelationship:@"geometry" withMapping:geoPointMapping];
[objectManager.mappingProvider registerMapping:criteriaMapping withRootKeyPath:@"criteria"];

// Build a serialization mapping by inverting our object mapping. Includes attributes and relationships
RKObjectMapping* criteriaSerializationMapping = [criteriaMapping inverseMapping];
// You can customize the mapping here as necessary -- adding/removing mappings
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:criteriaSerializationMapping forClass:[CRCriteria class]];
```